# Nodejs async queue (TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'drain' of object '#<Object>')

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, babeljs

Following is the queueClass.js :

```
const async = require('async');
export default class queueClass {
  constructor(requestObj) {
    this.queueMaxConnections = requestObj['queueMaxConnections'] || 10;
    this.queueMaxLength = requestObj['queueMaxLength'] || 4;
    
    this.msgQueue = async.queue(async (data, done) => {
        await this.handleCB(data, this.onData);
         done(data);
    }, 2); // queue maxparallelhandles -- concurrency

    this.msgQueue.drain = async () => {
        // some callback
    };
    
  }
}
```

I am importig this file in helper.js:

```
import queueClass from './queueClass'
var requestObj = {
 'queueMaxConnections': 5,
 'queueMaxLength':10
}
var queueVar = new queueClass(requestObj);
/* getting error in above line */
```

Error:
`TypeError: Cannot assign to read only property 'drain' of object '#<Object>'`

Can anybody tell me why it is happening and the possible solution for it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out, the drain property is not writable so you cannot just assign a new function to it.  However, the [async queue documentation](https://caolan.github.io/async/v3/docs.html#queue) shows that you can pass your function as a callback to drain.  In your case that looks like:

```
this.msgQueue.drain(async () => {
    // your drain code here
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I looked at the async repository code and I think it happens because `async.queue` has drain property `writable: false`. Please refer to https://github.com/caolan/async/blob/master/lib/internal/queue.js#L261

Comment: You're correct. He must pass a callback not reasign.

this.msgQueue.drain(() => { console.log('all done') })